# add meta to a product on cart WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

i'm trying to add product to the cart via PHP using this code,

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(20);
```

the product is getting into the cart but i would like to add custom meta as shown on the image
but i want to do that via PHP and not the backend

[image: meta preview]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after bit of reading throughout the code. I've found this

`$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product, $quantity, $variation, array('foo'=>'bar') );`

Comment: well, i'm unsure that this works in the latest version of WooCommerce, so cannot confirm, but as far as i recall you can provide `null` to variation