# Display and save added custom cart item data on Woocommerce Cart, Checkout and Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I am trying to add product in cart with cart item meta data. Here is the code :

```
$cart_item_data = array();

$cart_item_data['add_size'] = array('PR CODE'=>'1.0');

print_r(WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ,1,  0,array(), $cart_item_data ));
```

It's adding product in cart but it's not showing up in order or in cart.

Can any help me out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To display and save custom meta data added to cart in cart, checkout and orders when using:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ,1,  0,array(), array('add_size' => array('PR CODE'=>'1.0') );
```

You will use the following code:

```
// Display custom cart item meta data (in cart and checkout)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_cart_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 2 );
function display_cart_item_custom_meta_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $meta_key = 'PR CODE';
    if ( isset($cart_item['add_size']) && isset($cart_item['add_size'][$meta_key]) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'       => $meta_key,
            'value'     => $cart_item['add_size'][$meta_key],
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}

// Save cart item custom meta as order item meta data and display it everywhere on orders and email notifications.
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_cart_item_custom_meta_as_order_item_meta', 10, 4 );
function save_cart_item_custom_meta_as_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $meta_key = 'PR CODE';
    if ( isset($values['add_size']) && isset($values['add_size'][$meta_key]) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( $meta_key, $values['add_size'][$meta_key] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Example display on Cart *(and Checkout)* pages:**

[image]

**Example display on Orders (and email notifications):**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After I spent the last hours figuring things out I found out that the method has actually changed a bit over the time.

**Method:**

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
```

**In my case I needed to do this and the custom meta data got automatically displayed in the cart and order:**

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, NULL, NULL, array('your_key' => 'your_value'));
```

You can find out more here: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartadd_to_cart/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the product to the cart using the following code:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
```

Reference : https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#356-397

Have a look at this too: [add meta to a product on cart WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169389/add-meta-to-a-product-on-cart-woocommerce?rq=1)