# How to Dynamically Update Total Number of Additional Pets in WooCommerce Order Details and Subscription Totals on my account?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I've implemented a custom feature in my WooCommerce store that allows customers to add additional pets to a product with ID 76. This feature includes adding an input field for the number of additional pets and calculating the total price based on the quantity. The code is working well for adding the field, updating the cart, and displaying the information in the cart.

```php
// 1: Add the input field to the product page who's product id is 76
function add_pet_addon_field()
{
    global $product;
    if ($product->get_id() === 76) {
        echo '<div class="pet-addon-field">
                  <label for="pet-addon">Add Extra Pet $15 each (optional):</label>
                  <input type="number" id="pet-addon" name="pet_addon" value="0" min="0">
              </div>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_pet_addon_field');

// Add the extra pet price as cart item data

function add_extra_pet_price_to_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['pet_addon']) && $_POST['pet_addon'] > 0) {
        $addon_quantity = (int) $_POST['pet_addon'];
        $addon_price = 15;

        // Calculate the total price for the addons
        $addon_total = $addon_price * $addon_quantity;

        // Store the extra pet price as cart item data
        $cart_item_data['extra_pet_price'] = $addon_total;

        // Store the selected number of pets
        $cart_item_data['pet_addon'] = $addon_quantity;

        // Set the base price of the product as the sale price
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        if ($product->is_on_sale()) {
            $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
            $cart_item_data['extra_pet_base_price'] = $sale_price;
        } else {
            $cart_item_data['extra_pet_base_price'] = $product->get_regular_price();
        }
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_extra_pet_price_to_cart_item_data', 10, 3);


// Calculate the cart item price including the extra pet price
function calculate_cart_item_price($cart_object)
{
    foreach ($cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['extra_pet_price'])) {
            // Add the extra pet price to the cart item price
            $cart_item_base_price = $cart_item['extra_pet_base_price'];
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item_base_price + $cart_item['extra_pet_price']);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_cart_item_price');

// Adjust the price based on the number of extra pets when adding to the cart

function adjust_cart_item_price($cart_item_price, $cart_item)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['extra_pet_price'])) {
       
        // Calculate the total price for the cart item
        $cart_item_base_price = $cart_item['extra_pet_base_price'];
        $cart_item_price = ($cart_item_base_price + $cart_item['extra_pet_price']) * $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Update the value in the formatted price
        $formatted_price = '$' . number_format($cart_item_price, 2, '.', ',') . ' / month';

        return $formatted_price;
    }
    return $cart_item_price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'adjust_cart_item_price', 10, 2);


// Adjust the title based on the number of extra pets when displaying in the cart
function adjust_cart_item_title($cart_item_title, $cart_item)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['extra_pet_price'])) {
        // Get the selected number of extra pets from cart item data
        $selected_number_of_pets = isset($cart_item['pet_addon']) ? (int) $cart_item['pet_addon'] : 0;

        // Get the product link
        $product_link = $cart_item['data']->get_permalink();

        // Modify the cart item title to include the quantity and product link
        $cart_item_title = '<a href="' . esc_url($product_link) . '">' . $cart_item['data']->get_name() . '</a> + ' . $selected_number_of_pets . ' Additional Pet';

        return $cart_item_title;
    }
    return $cart_item_title;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'adjust_cart_item_title', 10, 2);
```

However, I'm facing two challenges:

**Order Details Update**: After checkout, I need to dynamically update the total number of selected additional pets in the order details table on the "Order Received" page. Currently, the order details show the product name, but it doesn't reflect the quantity of additional pets added.

**Subscription Totals Update**: I'm also using a subscription plugin to manage subscriptions in my WooCommerce store. I want to display the total number of additional pets and their corresponding prices in the Subscription Totals section on the "My Account" page, but I'm not sure how to integrate this custom feature with the subscription plugin.

I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to achieve these updates in both the order details and subscription totals sections.

Comment: There are many examples how to save your cart item data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505642/display-and-save-added-custom-cart-item-data-on-woocommerce-cart-checkout-and-o . As for the 2nd question if i understand correctly you want to get the total amount of additional pets from each order ? In this case you need to loop all order items get the number of additional pets you saved in your first question and the price and sum the results ?

Comment: The rule is one question at the time.